# Parse Server timeouts and iOS Parse SDK

Tags: parse-server

I've developed an iOS app that uses a Parse Server. Everything is working well so far.

In a near future, for different reasons, the server is going to be offline. Testing this scenario I've seen that my iOS app crashes after multiple retries to make calls to Parse. It's not processing properly the timeouts.

Even if I've tried to process correctly all possible responses from the server there are still crashes inside the SDK that I don't know how to fix.

I was thinking of canceling the queries in process but due to the project structure it's difficult to know which queries are being processed, so, is there any way to configure iOS SDK to cancel all requests directly or to stop all its processes?

I've been thinking in other possibility, is there any way to set Parse Server to maintenance mode so it responds with a specific header instead of responding with timeouts?